# Deploy R script in a portable usb form

Tags: r, deployment, usb, portable-applications

I have an R script which I want to deploy so that it's idiot-proof, one click runs it etc. Unfortunately I don't have the means to pay for a server, and the environment in which it needs to run does not allow the installation of new software, only portable style apps can be run. (School computers) My script also relies on several non-base packages.

Is there any way to deploy R and my script in an easy to run way so it can be used off a usb stick?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install R on a USB drive and use it on any computer running the same OS.  If you're using Windows, see [question 2.6](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#Can-I-run-R-from-a-CD-or-USB-drive_003f) of the [R for Windows FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html).

Comment: Will packages be installed to the usb as well?

Comment: I believe the default for Windows is to install packages in the in `R-2.1X.X/library/` directory, so yes.

Answer (score 3):

If you made the USB stick a bootable disk environment (say linux) with R installed on it, you could boot off it and do it that way.

Comment: ...and put your script in the .Rprofile file, inside .First(), so it is run when R is started: see http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html

Comment: Unfortunately I can't boot into an alternative OS, but thanks for the suggestion.